# symfony 2.8 and twig: undefined variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this code:

```
{% block vich_image_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="vich-image">
            {{ dump() }}
            {{ form_row(form.file) }}
            {% if form.delete is defined %}
                {{ form_row(form.delete) }}
            {% endif %}
            {{ download_uri }}
            {% if download_uri is defined and download_uri %}
                <a href="{{ download_uri }}"><img src="{{ download_uri | imagine_filter('my_thumb')}}" alt="" /></a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if show_download_link and download_uri is defined and download_uri%}
                <a href="{{ download_uri }}">{{ 'download'|trans({}, 'VichUploaderBundle') }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

That gave me this error:

```
Variable "download_uri" does not exist in offerte/edit.html.twig at line 21
```

where line 21 is :  `{{ download_uri }}`

But why do i get this error?,  twig uses `download_uri` in line 22 without any problems.

Comment: Uhm, does it ever read line 22 when it fails at 21?

Answer (score 1):

In line 22 it uses only if download_uri exists so that is why you get the error on line 21 it clearly says that this variable does´t exist because you did not pass it to this tmpl.

```
{% if download_uri is defined %}
{{download_uri}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not notice that in a case there was not a download_uri.

Answer (score 0):

In line 21 you are not checking if the variable is available therefore you will need to put it inside the if block:

```
 {% if download_uri is defined and download_uri %}
     {{ download_uri }}
     <a href="{{ download_uri }}"><img src="{{ download_uri | imagine_filter('my_thumb')}}" alt="" /></a>
 {% endif %}
```

also this:

```
{% if download_uri is defined and download_uri %}
```

should look like this:

```
{% if download_uri is defined and download_uri is not empty %}
```